# R How to do a simple vector/matrix calculation with conditions applied?

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I have a vector i.e.
change_vector (where dates are rownames)

```
2012-07-30  2012-08-06  2012-08-13  2012-08-20
100%    100%    150%    100%
```

and a matrix:

```
    2012-07-30  2012-08-06  2012-08-13  2012-08-20
2012-05-28  1.0 2.0 3.0 2.0
2012-06-04  1.0 2.0 3.0 2.0
2012-06-11  1.0 2.0 3.0 2.0
2012-06-18  1.0 2.0 3.0 2.0
2012-06-25  1.0 2.0 3.0 2.0
2012-07-02  1.0 2.0 3.0 2.0
2012-07-09  1.0 2.0 3.0 2.0
2012-07-16  1.0 2.0 3.0 2.0
2012-07-23  1.0 2.0 3.0 2.0
2012-07-30  1.0 2.0 3.0 2.0
2012-08-06  NA  2.0 3.0 2.0
2012-08-13  NA  NA  3.0 2.0
2012-08-20  NA  NA  NA  2.0
2012-08-27  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

I want to do a simple calculation, if I multiply the vector with my matrix
Then all the columns for 2012-08-13 will increase by 150%
i.e. to 4.5.. see this example where I did the calculation

```
t(t(my_matrix) * (change_vector)) 

    2012-07-30  2012-08-06  2012-08-13  2012-08-20
2012-05-28  1.0 2.0 4.5 2.0
2012-06-04  1.0 2.0 4.5 2.0
2012-06-11  1.0 2.0 4.5 2.0
2012-06-18  1.0 2.0 4.5 2.0
2012-06-25  1.0 2.0 4.5 2.0
2012-07-02  1.0 2.0 4.5 2.0
2012-07-09  1.0 2.0 4.5 2.0
2012-07-16  1.0 2.0 4.5 2.0
2012-07-23  1.0 2.0 4.5 2.0
2012-07-30  1.0 2.0 4.5 2.0
2012-08-06  NA  2.0 4.5 2.0
2012-08-13  NA  NA  4.5 2.0
2012-08-20  NA  NA  NA  2.0
2012-08-27  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

However what I want is to limit the multiplication so that it only counts the last 9 weeks relative to that date, for instance, column 2012-08-13 only increases to 4.5 for dates 9 weeks relative to the uplift date
i.e. the output should be:

```
    2012-07-30  2012-08-06  2012-08-13  2012-08-20
2012-05-28  1.0 2.0 3.0 2.0
2012-06-04  1.0 2.0 3.0 2.0
2012-06-11  1.0 2.0 4.5 2.0
2012-06-18  1.0 2.0 4.5 2.0
2012-06-25  1.0 2.0 4.5 2.0
2012-07-02  1.0 2.0 4.5 2.0
2012-07-09  1.0 2.0 4.5 2.0
2012-07-16  1.0 2.0 4.5 2.0
2012-07-23  1.0 2.0 4.5 2.0
2012-07-30  1.0 2.0 4.5 2.0
2012-08-06  NA  2.0 4.5 2.0
2012-08-13  NA  NA  4.5 2.0
2012-08-20  NA  NA  NA  2.0
2012-08-27  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

Please note in my real example, my matrix is quite large and the change vector will have a lot of different values

Thanks

Comment: Please make this more clear.  As it stands it's not clear what you're asking.  And please add *reproducible* data.

Comment: I added more details, does this help

Comment: You need to tell us whether we can depend on the NA's having the nice structure illustrated above.

Answer (score 1):

In the future, it's helpful if you post code to read in your data, using something like `dput()`.  Makes it easier for folks who might be willing to offer help.

```
change_vector <- structure(c(1, 1, 1.5, 1), 
    .Names = c("2012-07-30", "2012-08-06", "2012-08-13", "2012-08-20"))
my_matrix <- structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, NA, NA, NA, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, NA, NA, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    NA), .Dim = c(14L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("2012-05-28", "2012-06-04", 
    "2012-06-11", "2012-06-18", "2012-06-25", "2012-07-02", "2012-07-09", 
    "2012-07-16", "2012-07-23", "2012-07-30", "2012-08-06", "2012-08-13", 
    "2012-08-20", "2012-08-27"), c("2012-07-30", "2012-08-06", "2012-08-13", 
    "2012-08-20")))
```

The key here is to define another matrix that can be used as an indicator of whether or not the adjustment should be applied.  See the example code below.

```
# calculate the difference in weeks between the matrix and vector dates
mdates <- as.Date(dimnames(my_matrix)[[1]])
vdates <- as.Date(names(change_vector))
difweeks <- outer(mdates, vdates, "-") / 7
```

I've separated out the next few steps to try and make it clear what's going on.

```
# define a matrix that is 1 when the adjustment should be made, and 0 otherwise
adjonlyif <- 1*(difweeks >= -9)

# subtract 1 from the change vector
cv2 <- change_vector - 1

# multiply the adjusted change vector by the adjustment matrix, add 1, and multiply by the original matrix
my_matrix * (1 + t(t(adjonlyif) * cv2))
```

But, you could also just submit this in one line of code ...

```
my_matrix * (1 + t(t(difweeks >= -9) * (change_vector - 1)))
```

I wasn't sure if you just wanted to eliminate things older than 9 weeks (which is what I coded for) or if you needed to also eliminate things into the future (which you will have to modify the code to do).  Something like this ... instead of `difweeks >= -9` you would need something like `difweeks >= -9 & difweeks <= 0`.